# return and print the average of an input

Tags: python

I need help with a homework problem that i'm not sure how to go about since we didn't have time to go over it before our exam. 
"write a program that asks the user for the cost of lunch for five working days and prints out the average cost with two digits after the decimal point. You need to take input in the same line, where different values are separated by a space."

I believe that the first step would be to assign a variable to an input then use the split function but im stuck at that step

the question is available here http://courses.cse.tamu.edu/davidkebo/csce-110/labs/lab_2.pdf

```
lunch_cost = input("enter lunch cost: ").split()
```

Comment: You are correct on how to get the input into a list. Next you just need to do 3 things: 1) change all your inputs to `float` types, 2) add them all up, 3) divide by 5. Not sure how far into the class you are but you would normally validate that a correct input was given as well. You'll want to then find the method to round your `float` to the nearest hundredth. We can't answer this since it's a [homework problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and it says clearly in the instructions that you can't copy from another source.

Answer (score 0):

We shouldn't really give you too much help with this, because as @MyNamelsCaleb said in a comment, it states in linked PDF that you are not allowed to copy from another source.

So to get around this, I'll give you a basic idea of how to do this. All of these steps should be easy to work out or google.

- Your method for getting input is correct, but you need to split it at the comma.
- You then need to calculate the length of the list and save that to the variable.
- Then you can use the `sum()` function which will add the list together for you.
- Finally, you can compute the average by dividing the number `sum` returns by the length of the list.
- To size the output properly, that can be solved with a quick google.